# When installing MYSQL do I have to have MS Excel and Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MYSQL and following video tutorials. I don't own MS Office, why am I forced to instal MYSQL for excel and Visual studio? Can I skip those 2 parts?

Comment: what OS are you using? I am assuming windows? are you using community edition?

Comment: Windows 8 not community edition. Do I need to install the above 2 to be able to learn MYSQL?

Comment: The community edition was for the mysql install...No they are API connecting plugins..you should be able to deselect them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MySQL Installer for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-installer-gui.html) enables the installation of most all APIs by default, such as those, but you do not have to install them. Simply press "Next" and continue with the installation process. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-installer-gui.html) refers to other prerequisites, such as "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime", so you'll need that for MySQL Workbench (although you probably already have it installed). Basically, install the prerequisites for the applications you want to install, and skip the others.